# What does $a_i$ mean in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors, terminology, definition

I'm not understanding what a(sub i)s means in linear algebra. I'm just jumping into linear algebra without many other mathematics experience (Algebra 1, 2, and Geometry)

Also, what is n-vector?

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering, does the s only represent that A(sub i) is plural?

Comment: Yes, the s is only representing plural.

Comment: You're right, the "s" is just there to mean plurality. When they write $a_i$s, then mean "each number $a_i$"

Comment: "the $a_i$s are numbers" means "each $a_i$ [for $i=1, 2, \dots, n$] is a number", which means "$a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ are numbers".

Comment: $a_i$'s here mean the same thing as in: "Let $p(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots + a_1x+a_0$ be a polynomial."

Comment: Also, you can format maths here with MathJax. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

The $a_i$s represent the elements in the vector. For example if you have $\begin{align}
    a &= \begin{bmatrix}
           a_{1} \\
           a_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           a_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}$ where $a_1,...,a_n$ are in $\mathbb{R}$ then it could look something like $\begin{align}
    a &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           2 \\
           \vdots \\
           10
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}$ so $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, a_n = 10$

And an $n$-vector is just saying that there are $n$ elements (essentially telling you the size of the matrix). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Sure! If you think my answer is acceptable then would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 1):

An $n$-vector $a$ is an element of $\mathbf R^n$ or $\mathbf C^n$ (depending on the context) with $n$ entries, say $a=(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)$. Every entry $a_i$, where $i\in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$, is an element of $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$. The $`s`$ means, that *all* entrys have this property.